# Can I put other vegetables in a manual wheat grass juicer?

Tags: vegetables, juice, juicing

I'm thinking about buying a wheat grass juicer, but the fact that it only juices one thing gives me pause.  Are they adequate at juicing vegetables such as spinach, kale and carrots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, wheatgrass juicers are simply masticating juicers with smaller gears.  They work on the same principle as commercial masticating juicers, but with one 'chewing' gear instead of two, and a hand crank instead of a motor.  I read several reviews on Amazon about the Hurricane Stainless Steel wheatgrass juicer, and many indicated that it would juice leafy greens perfectly, but isn't so great with fruit or hard veggies (carrots).  This sounds good, as my main juicing concerns are for spinach, kale, wheatgrass, and turnip or mustard greens.

Answer (score 3):

Some juicers are better than other kinds for different things.  A dedicated wheat grass juicers probably isn't going to juice spinach, carrots, and kale well.

A centrifugal juice usually doesn't handle wheatgrass well and in general isn't supposed to be as efficient as some other kinds for leafy greens.

A single-gear or double-gear masticating juicer works great for leafy greens, but isn't supposed to be as efficient for softer fruit.

If you're looking for something that will do wheatgrass, leafy greens, and a variety of other things - consider something like the [Omega 8004](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RLYOEE).  Long warranty, easy to clean, and gives good quality juice.  If you need to make juice for a lot of people though, it is kind of slow for large quantities.

Comment: I've had my eye on the Omega 8004, but it's just too far out of my budget range.  Plus, I like the compactness of the wheatgrass juicers, and that they don't require electricity.